# oracle sql loader unable to read from pipe

Tags: java, linux, oracle, pipe, sql-loader

I'm using named pipe along with **Oracle SQL*Loader** to load some 20 millions rows into database.

The source of the pipe is from a Java application which write to the pipe using simple **FileOutputStream**.

It can be observed that the Oracle SQL*Loader need to wait a lot on the Java application to produce enough data for loading.

The waiting is fine. However, the Oracle SQL*Loader always exist after loading about 1 million rows with output like:

```
SQL*Loader-501: Unable to read file (upipe.dat)
SQL*Loader-560: error reading file
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
```

And in this case, the Java will throw IOException with information:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:284)
```

It runs on Linux environment.
Any idea why this will happen?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe sqlloader is trying to buffer data and can't get more data from named pipe (perhaps its ok to wait for first amt of data in beginning, but it doesn't want to wait mid-load).  My guess is that sqlldr process caught up to java process and couldn't read more data, and also did NOT see an EOF, so it assumed some issue reading the "file"

Comment: Is that the full stack dump?  These are usually Socket IO errors, typically when you get a socket timeout.

Comment: this is the full stack where the error comes from, the rest of the stack is from my own application

Comment: the waiting seems happening all the time. cause the sql loader consumes the data much faster than what java produces. it looks suddenly it fails for no particular reason..